# How to insert data in wordpress using where condition

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to insert data in wp_postmeta table in wordpress using where condition how to add where condition in below code

```html
$wpdb->insert($table_name, array('meta_key' => '_wc_shipment_tracking_items', 'meta_value' => $tracking_id) );
```

`

Comment: If you need a where condition, you're looking for an `update` query. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do insert new data or want to update existing table data? 
If you are inserting new data then there no need of where clause whereas if you are updating existing data then you should use update Statement.